# Writing to Amazon S3 bucket from Lambda results in "InvalidARN: ARN accountID does not match regex "[0-9]{12}""

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

Been digging through tutorials for days, but they all say the same thing, and it seems like I should be in slam dunk territory here, but I get the above error whenever I try to read or write from my Amazon S3 bucket.

I only have one AWS account, so my lambda function should be owned by the same account as my Amazon S3 bucket. I have given my lambda role s3:GetObject and PutObject permissions, as well as just s3:*, I have verified that my S3 bucket policy is not denying access explicitly, but nothing changes the message.

I am new to AWS policies and permissions, but google isn't giving up a lot of other people getting this message. I don't know where I am supposed to be supplying my AccountID or why it isn't already there. Would be grateful for any insights.

EDIT: I have added AmazonS3FullAccess to my policies and removed my previous policy, which only allowed GetObject and PutObject specifically. Sadly, behavior has not changed.

Here are a couple of screenshots:
[image]
[image]

And, since my roles seem to be correct, here is my code, any chance there is anything here that could be causing my problem?

[image]

Comment: What is the policy?

Comment: Paste your lambda execution policy

Comment: I had an inline policy specifying GetObject and PutObject, but I have since replaced it with the standard AmazonS3FullAccess policy, however my problem persists. :-(

Answer (score 7):

You should use the bucket name only - without the full arn stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by ensuring that the IAM role associated with your Lambda function has the correct permissions. For example, here is the IAM role i use to invoke Amazon S3 operations from a Lambda function:

[image]

Also make sure in the Lambda console, you select the proper IAM role, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response!! Can you think of anything else that could be contributing to this problem, though? I added the S3FullAccess policy, but behavior did not change.

Comment: When you configured your Lambda function -- did you specify the correct IAM role in the AWS Management Console. That is the only thing i can think of. See this AWS tutorial to see how we can give an IAM role (used in a Lambda function) the proper permissions so the Lambda function can invoke AWS Services. This is implemented in Java, but will show you how to configure an IAM role used in a Lambda function to invoke multiple services -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/workflow_multiple_channels

Comment: I created a new role for this function, but I feel fairly confident that this is the role I am adding policies to, because I am getting to it by clicking on it on the lambda function details page in the console.

Comment: The only policies on this role currently are AmazonS3FullAccess and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.

Comment: I do notice however that the Path says "/service-role/" rather than "/", could this be significant?

Comment: Those look correct from an IAM role perspective. If you selected this IAM role from the Lambda role - your code should work.

Comment: Hm, well dang. I wonder what my issue is? I have included a screenshot of my code above, in case there is anything obviously broken in there...

Comment: Follow this AWS JavaScript tutorial - this has been tested and works. Once you get this working, you an apply it to your project -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/scheduled-events-invoking-lambda-example.html

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: (Sorry, I guess I lack the reputation to move this to chat...) Are you sure that is the tutorial you meant to link though? It appears to be a cron job that reads from dynamoDB and fires off SNS, not seeing any S3 there...

Comment: This will show you how to invoke AWS services from Lambda using JS API. It will help you learn the entire end to end process.

Comment: Also - look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html  (the bucket name is used - not the ARN value as your code shows )

Comment: OMG it was the bucket name!! Thank you so much. Still didn't create my file, but got rid of the error, I will read those docs you mentioned and proceed from here. Thank you!!!

Comment: Your welcome! If you have any more issues. feel free to connect to me on Linked In. Profile shows my linked in.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue but I later realized I provided s3 arn instead of the bucket name as an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I had incorrect REGION in S3Client inicialization. Here is the correct code example (change region to yours):

```
const REGION = "eu-central-1"; //e.g. "us-east-1"
const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: REGION });
```

Source: step 2 in [AWS Getting started in Node.js Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html)